# How to resolve Jackson Databind InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type (Illegal type to deserialize)?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to map a JsonNode to a 3rd-party object using Jackson's ObjectMapper. The target class is `HikariConfig.class` and has a default constructor and getter and setter for all necessary properties. The class contains complex data structures like ThreadFactory or ScheduledExecutorService. The project framework is Spring Boot 3.0.2 (version numbers predefined by Spring Boot: Tomcat 10.1.5, Jackson 2.14.1, Hikari 5.0.1).

The JsonNode is flat structured and looks like this:

```json
{
  "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:h2:mem:example-db",
  "driverClassName": "org.h2.Driver",
  "username": "sa",
}
```

Since unknown properties are not to be processed, and also in order to ignore the complex data structures, a Mixin comes into play:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private static abstract class HikariConfigMixin {

    @JsonIgnore private static char[] ID_CHARACTERS;
    @JsonIgnore private DataSource dataSource;
    @JsonIgnore private Properties dataSourceProperties;
    @JsonIgnore private ThreadFactory threadFactory;
    @JsonIgnore private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor;
    @JsonIgnore private MetricsTrackerFactory metricsTrackerFactory;
    @JsonIgnore private Object metricRegistry;
    @JsonIgnore private Object healthCheckRegistry;
    @JsonIgnore private Properties healthCheckProperties;
}
```

And here now the usage of the ObjectMapper:

```java
HikariConfig config = new ObjectMapper()
        .addMixIn(HikariConfig.class, HikariConfigMixin.class)
        .readerFor(HikariConfig.class)
        .readValue(jsonNode);
```

Unfortunately this will throw the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`: Illegal type (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons
```

Here the complete stack strace:

```
2023-02-15 04:10:24,988 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender DataBase org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:165)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:683)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:641)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:624)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:560)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:162)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupInfo(SpringApplication.java:614)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:387)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:105)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:53)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.connectAndPrepare(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:592)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.connectAndStart(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:613)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeThrough(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:888)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`: Illegal type (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at com.example.config.Log4j2ConnectionFactory.mixin(Log4j2ConnectionFactory.java:210)
    at com.example.config.Log4j2ConnectionFactory.<clinit>(Log4j2ConnectionFactory.java:73)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`: Illegal type (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadTypeDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1887)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.SubTypeValidator.validateSubType(SubTypeValidator.java:302)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory._validateSubType(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:415)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:648)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2386)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1724)
    at com.example.config.Log4j2ConnectionFactory.mixin(Log4j2ConnectionFactory.java:198)
    ... 36 more
```

By the way, the exact same error is thrown even if no Mixin is applied.

### My question:

Can anyone tell why `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig` is an illegal type that must not be deserialized for security reasons and how to fix this?

**Many thanks for any help**